# Laravel 5.2 eloquent save auto increment pgsql exception on same id

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, eloquent, plpgsql

I'm new to laravel 5.2 and postgres pgsql.
I have a table named `logs`

```
Schema::create('logs', function(Blueprint $table){
                $table->bigIncrements('id');
                $table->text('exception');
                $table->dateTime('created_at');
            });
```

and a model accordingly `Log`

```
    class Log extends Model{
        public $incrementing = true;
        public $timestamps = false;
}
```

According to my understanding(wrong may be). If `id` not given, then Eloquent puts last used id + 1 (but not null against it).
If I am saving first `Log`, surely id will be 1 for it and will be 2 for next one. 
Suppose I have added only one record with Eloquent `save()` with `id=1`

But here comes the problem, If I somehow (manually with an insert query, or with csv file) add new records with id `2,3,5,8` e.t.c. in the table. But programmatically on `save`,
Eloquent still sets `id = 2` for second `Log` record/entity.

I'm now saving like this

```
$l = new Log();
$l->exception = "some exception";
$l->created_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

while(true){
    try{
          $l->save(); //it auto increments the id on each try
          break;
    }catch(\Exception $e){
          continue;
    }
 }
```

Watch the loop, above solution works for me and it will automatically add record with `id = 4` (given above conditions). It throws and catches two exceptions for id 2 and 3.

I don't like this solution, please suggest me something else, I'm searching for a fix without loop, for almost 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first column auto increment if you  need add one more column insert value like this take a maximum value of that column add +1 then save

Ex:column name **log_id** then in your store function take maximum of **log_id** and add **+1**

```
$current_id = DB::table('logs')->max('log_id');

'log_id' => $current_id + 1,
```

or else change your **id** column as **integer** and take max value add **+1**

Comment: Yes that's good. But that will kill the benefit of serial data type. Let's see it this way, On a very large database (millions of records), what would be more efficient `max('log_id') + 1;` or that `try catch` loop? I think max one is better may be.

Comment: yes kind of, avoided that loop, by simply saving `$l->save();` in try.

 and in catch, your suggested way.